# How To Configure PyCharm for appium(android automation)

Tags: python, appium, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to do android automation with pycharm+appium in ubuntu 16.04 OS,i installed with appium and pycharm. now i need help [How To Configure PyCharm for appium-android automation]

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to make any changes in PyCharm for your appium code to run. You need to make your appium configuration right and then use those in the PyCharm code. Please see this http://scrolltest.com/2015/05/02/step-by-step-mobile-app-testing-with-appium-in-python/

Comment: Hi I tried as per the content in url.. wich u shared, i am not able to launch already installed app. (settings app). OS:Ubuntu 16.04 Python version 2.7.12 , appium v1.6.4

Comment: HI, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: i use your method to launch a pre-installed android application it throws message as "Process finished with exit code 0"it does not throw me any error also.      OS-Version- Ubuntu 16.04, Appium version 1.6.4, pythin version 2.7.12..  can you please tell me what is the procedure i should follow to launch the pre-installed application.

Comment: Either add this as a new question or edit the existing question with more information.